# Not able to get full path name of file in html form for express mutler

Tags: html, node.js, express, multer

I am having some difficulty getting the full path for a file from a form html. I understand that browser do not allow that. I have done some search in stackoverflow and unable to resolve the issue. I may have missed out something simple or straight forward.

The task is to open a file (etc "readme.txt") from user selected location. If  the file is from the same folder location as the script, it will work. If the file is in a different folder, it will fail. The error stack is as below.

Basically I am using a html form , and the server is express and mutler. Using postman , I am able to open the file by specifying the full path in postman, so I conclude the problem lies in the form as I am not able to get the full path of the file.

My question (after quite some inconclusive search of googling / stackoverflow) : how do I get the full pathname for the file through the html form ? If I can't (due to browser security), what are the ways that I can go around this as I like to open the file.

Thanks for pointing me to the right direction (or searches) !

```
    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/upload" >
        <div>
            <label>Select your profile picture:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="btn_upload_profile_pic" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

server

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require ('body-parser')
var fs = require ('fs')
var multer = require('multer')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express ();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },

    // By default, multer removes file extensions so let's add them back
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })


app.post ("/upload",  (req, res)=>{


    console.log (JSON.stringify (req.body.file))


    const content = fs.readFileSync(req.body.file, 'utf8');
    console.log(content);

    res.send (content)


})


app.listen (port, ()=>{

    console.log ('Server is up on port ' + port)
})
```

The error stack if I open the file (from the html form) from another a different location

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'readmefolder.txt'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:451:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:353:35)
    at /Users/dev/Development/node/mutlertest/playground/servertest.js:44:24
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/dev/Development/node/mutlertest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/dev/Development/node/mutlertest/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/dev/Development/node/mutlertest/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/dev/Development/node/mutlertest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/dev/Development/node/mutlertest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/dev/Development/node/mutlertest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/dev/Development/node/mutlertest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multer middleware in your `app.post ("/upload")` route, here you can find detailed instruction:
https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: Thanks Yura, I have look into it. I can get the file name , but it does not solve my issue of not getting a full path name. I tested it out in postman and mutler works (since I am able to put a full pathname in postman) .  However, via the form , I have difficulty getting the full path.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer after more digging and help.

Basically i restructure the form into something like this

```
      <form id="uploadForm"
         enctype="multipart/form-data"
         action="/api/photo"
         method="post">
      <input type="file" name="textfile" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
      <span id = "status"></span>
    </form>
```

The filename is in req.file.filename in the app.post (/upload).